# Repeating Dialogflow Intent Until Condition is Met

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using Python and the Dialogflow V2 API. I would like to know how to reprompt an intent until a condition is met using Python Flask as the fulfillment. I am filling slots and then running an SQL query to verify the user's identity. If the query returns false (there is no identity that exists in the database), then I would like to rerun the intent until the condition is met (userId is found).

I have tried looking at the JS documentation, but cannot find any Python documentation for accomplishing the feat.

Comment: Hm. I think I might have a solution but don't know how to implement it. Is there a way to trigger a fallback intent if a query run in the previous intent does not satisfy a condition? EX: userId is not found in the database after a user gives their name.

Answer (score 1):

In the fulfillment, if condition is false, just reply with the same question like `Sorry this username does not exist, please enter the username again.`

```
if not username:
    res = json.dumps({
        "fulfillmentText": "Sorry this username does not exist, please enter the username again."
    })
```

If you have some input context for the intent as well, then you need to set he context from the fulfillment as well.

```
req = request.get_json()
if not username:
    res = json.dumps({
        "outputContexts": [
            {
                "name": "{}/contexts/ask-username".format(req['session']),
                "lifespanCount": 1,
            },
        ],
            "fulfillmentText": "Sorry this username does not exist, please enter the username again."
        })
```

**EDIT:**
To reset a parameter value, include the parameter in the output context as well in the webhook, and set `#context.parameter` as the default value of parameter in dialogflow console.
[Documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/actions-parameters) for setting default value of entity from context.

```
 "outputContexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/agent/sessions/${SESSION_ID}/contexts/ask-username",
            "lifespanCount": 1,
            "parameters": {
                "foo": ""
            }
        }
    ]
```

[image: default value]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @sid8491 Is there a way to "go back"/clear a slot and get the next response from the user if the condition is not yet met? Similar to Rasa NLU's [UserUtteranceReverted()](https://rasa.com/docs/core/_modules/rasa_core/events/#UserUtteranceReverted)?

Comment: @JAWS007 yes, you can include the slot in the output context and set their value to NULL, in the intent set default value of slot to `#context.slot`

Comment: Awesome @sid8491. Is there perhaps some documentation for this? Thanks.